# Create a hook with a consumer (provider/consumer)

Tags: reactjs

How can I create a hook based on a consumer and provider?
The reason for why I am asking this is because the Provider and Consumer is exported from another library, so I can not extract that part more than that, and I would like a neat way to just add a value to the useHook to populate wanted values.

```
// I have a provider somewhere above this part, and here is the consumer:
<MyConsumer>
  {props => <Values {...props} />}
</MyConsumer>
```

I would like to create a hook that returns the values I get inside the `Values` component. And maybe the best is to include the `MyConsumer` inside that hook so I would not need "two lines of code" where I want to use the hook.

I am imagining something like:

```
const useValues = (props) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({});

  // do stuff

  return state;
}
```

As mention, I do not know what I should do about the `MyConsumer` part.

Thank you for any help

Comment: This sounds like a simple use case for React Context, unless you have a specific need that I don't understand

Comment: I should probably mention that this Provider and Consumer is exported from another library, so I can not extract that part more than that

Comment: So am I understanding you correctly that instead of using the Consumer you just want to use a hook to consume the values?

Comment: Yes, something like that. The reason is that there is a lot of setup inside the `<Values />` that I would like to skip for every use.

Comment: Does my answer help?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using your own context to wrap the provider and consumer.

```
const MyStateCtx = createContext();
const useMyState = () => useContext(MyStateCtx);

// LibraryProvider and LibraryConsumer are the provider and consumer
// supplied by the library you're using.
const MyStateProvider = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <LibraryProvider>
      <LibraryConsumer>
        {(props) => (
          <MyStateCtx.Provider value={props}>{children}</MyStateCtx.Provider>
        )}
      </LibraryConsumer>
    </LibraryProvider>
  );
};

const ConsumingComponent = () => {
  // You can consume state here with this hook ✨
  const myState = useMyState();

  return <div />;
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <MyStateProvider>
      <div>
        <ConsumingComponent />
      </div>
    </MyStateProvider>
  );
}
```

[Codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-poincare-ovk00?file=/src/App.js)